# Oracle Standard Edition Insallation Issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We are developing a WPF application with back-end as Oralce 11g. I am using LLBLGen ORM tool generated code as DAL Layer. We have the requirement that the application should able to connect both central database (server) and local database(Oracle standard edtion is to be installed in local machine without any clusters).

My Current Configuration:

1. I have Win 7 64 bit installation.
2. I have an Oracle client installation (32 bit) for ODP.Net.
3. I have an Xcopy installation of ODP.Net 64 bit in my system (this is installed for LLBLGen Designer(64bit) to work). The base path is "C:\Oracle" and the Registry entry in "Key_odac".

I need to install Oracle Standard edition(32 bit) without any database. They(client) have supplied a batch file which install our application database in the local system. The base path for oracle standard edition given is "C:\Oracle" and the database path is given as "C:\Oracle\DB11202". But when I tried the installtaion with above enviroment it is giving errors (at the end with insufficinet privileges).

During the batch file execution I was asked to supply name for a dummy file,second name,meta data file name for xdb,etc. These are not faced my co-worked who is in onsite and he has a different environment than me(no 64 bit installation).

Could anybody suggest a better way to keep all the products exists without affecting others? Or shall I need to uninstall any of the products/Whether I need to mention a different path for standard edition?

Also please mention that How to install the oracle std edition database as administrator (using the batch file provided).

Comment: I have figured out the issue. The base directory for ODP.Net 64 bit installtion and Oracle std.Edition installation is set as same. So I have uninstalled all oracle client (ODP.net 32 and 64 bit) and re-install the oracle standard edition again. It is now working. Please note that Oracle standard edition installtaion not updated my machine.config for .net 4.0 for Oracle.DataAccess entry. I have manually put in machine.config.